# How to create RestFull api with express and node.js?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I am very new to node and express i read some documentation but i did not get any solid understanding how to create rest api with node, So with below basic code i just want to create get api with express and return response to angularjs factory method.I would like to get help and better understanding for the following .

1- How to return response with GET api ?

2- If we have json object how can i pass that data using GET api ?

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');

var app = express();
app.use(express.static('./'));

var server = app.listen(3000, function(){
    var host = server.address().address;
    var port = server.address().port;
    console.log('Example app listening at http',host,port);
});

app.get('/test', function(req, res) {
  res.type('text/plain'); // set content-type
  res.send('i am a beautiful butterfly'); // send text response
});
```

workerController.js

```
$scope.getTestData = function(){
        alert('got function working');
        workerFactory.getData().then(function(response){
            var dataResponse = response.data;
            console.log(dataResponse);
        })
    }
```

workerFactory.js

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('workerFactory', function ($http) {
    'use strict';
    return {
        getData: function(){
            return $http.get('/test');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: `res.send()` or `res.json()` are two typical ways to send your response to a REST request.  You appear to already be doing that in your `app.get()` handler.  What else are you expecting or looking for?

Comment: when i call get endpoint /test from front end i do not see the message "I am a beautiful butterfly"

Comment: What response do you get when you call that endpoint?  If you aren't getting any response, then add an error handler to your `getData()` call so you can see what error you're getting.

Comment: Also, `app.use(express.static('./'));` is generally a bad idea as that will allow people to see all your server source files and even things like https certificates (if present).  You should make a separate sub-directory that only contains publicly served files and point `express.static()` at that sub-directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the second part, how to pass a JSON object back.  You can change your API code to something like:

```
app.get('/test', function(req, res) {
  res.json({message: 'i am a beautiful butterfly'}); // send a JSON response
});
```

I'm just working on the first part of the question

Comment: nearly forgot, to send an object in the POST just add a second argument  to a POST call e.g. return $http.post('/test', objectToSend);

Comment: What does this have to do with the specific question and the specific code the OP presented?  They have code already to request and handle a route.  They want to know why it isn't working.

Comment: The original question is posted by someone who is new to Node, I have provided a more structured approach to controlling the routes and also shown in the code that it must be a POST and written to the console where the input has been provided.  Happy to take feedback if this can be explained in a more simple structure but I believe it answers the original questions.

Comment: Why are you telling the OP they must use a "POST"?  It appears they are just getting data.

Comment: I have interpreted the second part of his question as that they are trying to pass an object to the API.  This is not recommended as a GET but should be a POST.  Happy to correct my code if this is a misunderstanding of the question they are asking

Comment: I think they're trying to return an object from the server as the result of the GET.

Comment: @aftab - can you confirm if you are just looking to return an object as part of the GET or receive an object as part of the request to the API.  I will then adjust my answer accordingly

Comment: @Autobat Yes i am trying to GET the object from the server so i can display object properties to the  front end

Comment: I would appreciate if you can explain with my example object return with GET

Comment: @aftab I cant see anything wrong with the code regarding seeing the response in your browsers console.  Can you provide both the browser and node's console output when running the application - i will see if i can find the issue

Comment: @Autobat thanks i got the understanding how to work with GET, Thanks again for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a full working REST-full API code by using [Amplication](https://amplication.com), it's an open-source for generating Node.js code by only defining your data model.

Answer (score 0):

As you have the basic understanding on REST API you can use this node module 
https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-node for creating great REST API.